# How to test conductivity of copper wire?

Tags: wire, copper

I purchased 90 meters of 0.35mm2 stranded copper conductor wire. How can I test this wire for conductivity to ensure quality copper was used?

Comment: Is one length of 90m or 10m from each supplier?

Comment: I think you need to figure out what is important in your application. If it is just conductivity then a resistance measurement will give you what you need to know. If it's insulation then you need to do an insulation test. If it's flexibility then ...

Comment: What's "high quality" for you?

Comment: If you're basing large purchases on small initial samples, you should beware the "golden sample" phenomenon as well as "quality fade". It's best to establish objective quantitative metrics and inspect at the factory to ensure they are maintained.

Comment: 90 meters were purchased from each supplier. I believe conductivity is most important for my application. The insulation is teflon and resistant to high temperatures which suits my application and is flexible enough as well. My definition of high quality would be using decent copper and not substandard, as the wire I purchased was the pricier silver plated copper and not the tin plated. I will be purchasing in only small batches and would like to use the same testing criteria for future purchases. Golden sample? Sounds like you know the deal with these Asia suppliers!

Comment: Been there, done that, found we were being sold wire with resistivity of about 120% IACS.  Since this size wire has only about 50milliohms per meter, you need to carefully set up a 4 point (Kelvin) measurement with the voltage probes a defined distance apart (we made up a jig for repeatability) with the current connections outside the length you measure voltage over. It may be that you get worse conductivity wire that still meets the per unit length resistance by dint of there being larger stranding, unless weight is an issue that will still meet your needs.

Comment: That would be around AWG 22 with an Ampacity of unbundled wire at 10A @ 90'C and ~  5 Ohms / 90 m.  Thus verify resistance then if temp matters out 10A thru each sample in series and eliminate the hottest.  Why not Magnet wire?  If used for RF, then put thru 10A of RF which due to skin effect will indicate silver plating thickness by the smallest drop in voltage per supplier  Make a twisted pair Balun or RF test conductance.

Comment: Building a testing jig is the way to go. May I ask for clarification regarding "the current connections outside the length you measure voltage over" ? For example if the length is 10M, voltage probes at the 2M, 4M, 6M, 8M marks, current connections at the 0M and 10M marks?

Answer (score 2):

measure the resistance: connect a 2A (or whatever load) in series with the wire and measure the voltage drop across the wire.

compare that with the published resistance for pure copper wire of similar cross section.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCd2Xl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>